# How can I paste specific data from a workbook to another Workbook with VBA? I have a program but it was for sheets. What can I do to fix?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I paste specific data from a workbook to another Workbook with VBA? I have a program but it was for sheets. What can I do to fix?

I tried to verify other codes online but couldnt find a way to fix. Im new to VBA so any help would be awesome! Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a  
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "KSR" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Cut

            Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kevinsaldala\Desktop\TEST1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

            b = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kevinsaldala\Desktop\TEST1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kevinsaldala\Desktop\TEST1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

            ActiveSheet.Paste    
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate          
        End If     
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a lot to unpack, but  you first need to do some research :) Try starting here https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-tutorial-1/#Writing_values_to_cells

Comment: Thanks @Marcucciboy2 I appreciate the help!

Comment: Probably worth stating where exactly you want to copy from (which workbook, worksheet and range) as well as to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, we can use the code resembles the following to copy data from workbook to workbook （Copy the Row doesn't work now, so if we want to copy data of entire row, we can use for/for-each to handle the data of the entire row）:

```
Sub Test8()
Dim a As Long, b As Long
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet

  Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet4")
  Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\test.xlsx")
  Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
  a = sourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To a
        If sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "KSR" Then
            'sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy
             sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Copy

            targetWorksheet.Activate

            b = targetWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

            targetWorksheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

            'MsgBox "A" & (b + 1)

            targetWorksheet.Paste

            sourceSheet.Activate
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

If we want to copy entire specified sheet, just iterate over the UsedRange.

Comment: I would recommend changing the variable names for `workbook` and `worksheet` so that they don't mistakenly line up with any reserved words and cause problems.